# How to trigger an event using pyquery python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, pyquery

I'm trying to automate a headless web browser using python and packages like pyquery, beautiful soup, requests, mechanize.

But so far I haven't found a right way to trigger a click event on a button. For example, to fill an online form, I'm able to insert values in the text fields, but not able to click on the Submit/Send button.

Comment: Why not selenium?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery), pyquery isn't a library to interact with JS code (at least not yet). It is used to parse HTML Docs like beautiful soup.

As Nehal suggested, [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is your best bet.

Comment: Selenium is for UI testing. I am developing an engine that dont need to invoke a browser. All code based.